# How do I add an avatar when signing up a user with Parse (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a function which successfully adds a user to the User table in my Parse class, but I want to add an avatar to the signup form.

The stoyboard side of things is working fine, and I can select and image from the camera or photo library and add it to my imageView (profilePic) but when I try to add this to the signUpInBackground method, it crashes the app.

I am a complete newb to ios development, but am familiar with other coding languages so it's not all completely foreign, I just don't know what I am missing here or whether it's just not possible to add an image at signup?

Help!

```
let user = PFUser()

user.email = emailAddress.text
user.username = screenName.text
user.password = password.text

let image = self.profilePic.image

if image != nil {

    let imagedata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)!

        let file = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imagedata)

        user["profilePic"] = file

    }

    user.signUpInBackground(block: { (success, error) in

        if error != nil {

            // error code

        } else {

            // user logged in successfully

        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do. I added validation for to it as well. Also i created it that once successful signup, log the user then in. You can remove that if you don't want it.  This is a `swift3` example!

```
@IBOutlet weak var avatarImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var emailAddress: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var password: UITextField!

// MARK: - UPLOAD AVATAR BUTTON
@IBAction func uploadAvatarButt(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: APP_NAME,
        message: "Select source",
        preferredStyle: .alert)

    let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a picture", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })

    let library = UIAlertAction(title: "Pick from library", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })

    // Cancel button
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in })

    alert.addAction(camera)
    alert.addAction(library)
    alert.addAction(cancel)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

// ImagePicker delegate
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        avatarImage.image = image
    }
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// MARK: - SIGNUP BUTTON
@IBAction func signupButt(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    if  password.text == "" || emailAddress.text == "" || screenName.text == "" {

           //You can alert  here , that fields need to be filled. 

    } else {
        let userForSignUp = PFUser()
        userForSignUp.username = screenName.text!.lowercased()
        userForSignUp.password = password.text
        userForSignUp.email = emailAddress.text

        if avatarImage.image != nil {
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(avatarImage.image!, 0.8)
            let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.jpg", data:imageData!)
            // profilePic needs to be the name of the col 
            userForSignUp["profilePic"] = imageFile
        }


        userForSignUp.signUpInBackground { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

              //Signup Success
                PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: self.screenName.text!, password:self.password.text!) { (user, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        //Login Success
                    } else {
                        //Login Falied
                    }}
            // ERROR
            } else {
               //Signup Failed
        }}
    }
}
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you so much! Rather than replacing all my code with all yours, I wanted to check line by line what was different, and the only thing I could find that was different was the fact that you were saving a Jpeg rather than a Png - so I changed it and it worked. It looks like the default images in the IOS simulater, when saved as a PNG are more than 10mb which is what was causing the crash! Thank you so much for your help with this!